# Private Data Class vs Member Variables

Tags: c++

Where I work there are two distinct styles of coding:

1. Some programmers will create a class within the class they are working and store member data variables there.
2. Others declare member variables within the class and mark them private.

I was curious as to which is better, assuming one is.  Also, what benefit does creating a private class give you?  Is this just an old school vs new school thing?

For example:

```
class CPOMSCTE104DeviceCOMHandler
{
public:
    //Stuff

private:
    class CPrivateData;
    std::auto_ptr<CPrivateData> m_cPrivateData; //All member variables go in here
    friend class CPrivateData;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hesitating to flag this, but it seems like it will be either too broad or all opinion here.

Comment: OP, Can you provide any additional context to slim down the topic space here?  I.E. what these things are used for, is this occurring in publicly distributed headers vs. pure internal code? Where are they defining their 'private' class.  Sounds like attempts at doing opaque pointers and 'pImpl' (private implementation) of sorts so that they can hide the implementation from the interface.

Comment: Note that you must provide a user defined destructor for this class or you risk running into undefined behavior...

Comment: @UpAndAdam:  I did not hesitate.  Any question which boils down to "which is better?" is almost always off-topic here.  This question is no exception.

Comment: @JohnDibling Thanks, do you go to broad for those or answers are opinions?

Comment: When it comes to questions of style, I first as *different* questions in order to find out what the technical differences are between two methods.  Then I decide for myself which is better.  I don't my opinions prescribed by a herd.

Comment: It's sad that there is a legitimate answer to my question, both technical and stylistic (Thank you Marek Rogosz!), but posters have jumped to the "Flagged" response all to quickly.  If you aren't knowledgeable enough in a field to to respond to a thread, don't flag it just to be a jerk!

Comment: I didn't vote to close your question to "be a jerk."  I voted to close your question because it doesn't fit the guidelines for StackOverflow.  Of course, you read the FAQ and read over some questions here before posting your own question in order to discover what kinds of questions are acceptable and what are not -- but then you decided to post this *solidly* off-topic question anyway.  Did you do that "just to be a jerk?"

Comment: John Dibling: 

One of the posting guidelines "practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development" and the answer to my question (in short) "It is widely used to boost building times and to remove implementation details from the header file in the cost of additional memory allocation." which is part if the PIMPL idiom (Marek Rogosz)

Call me crazy, but it appears I asked a specific enough question that another poster could give me a specific answer.  I followed the guidelines just fine.  What's your excuse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern with nested private class is called the PIMPL idiom

https://anteru.net/2009/03/14/385/

It is widely used to boost building times and to remove implementation details from the header file in the cost of additional memory allocation.

Comment: It's not just used to boost building times, particularly as it doesn't necessarily accomplish that. Primarily it hides and decouples implementation. In terms of memory, it adds a pointer which isn't exactly high cost.